# How to implement in Python Flet a BottomAppBar

Tags: python, flet

I have an extra Page and want to add an BottomAppBar. Here the Code:

Main and Start are Different files, but start can use page
In the Documentation it shows, that i just have to add the page.BottomAppBar. I tried to add it in the main(), this was working

```
#Main:

import flet
from flet import *

from pages.start import StartPage

    
def main(page: Page):
    app = Startgage(show_game_page ,page)
    page.add(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flet.app(
        target=main,
        assets_dir='assets')
    
#Start:
class StartPage(UserControl):

    def __init__(self, show_game_page, page):
        super().__init__()
        self.show_game_page = show_game_page
        self.page = page

    def build(self):

        self.page.bottom_appbar = BottomAppBar(
            content=self.player_row,
            bgcolor=colors.GREY_400,
            visible=True,
        )
        #[...]
```

I just want to see the BottomAppBar

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `self.page.bottom_appbar`, you need to call `self.page.update()` to update the page, and your bottom app bar will be displayed in the app.